# Django admin/frontend authentication issue

Tags: django

I am developing an application using **Django 1.4**. When I log into admin site in another tab in the browser, the application interface in which I am already logged in automatically logs out. Please help me in solving this issue. The browser I am using is **Firefox**. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Admin is also a user in `django`. So, you can't have more than one user logged in at the same time in the same browser, can you? Try the same scenario on facebook. This is what it is. You re fine, there's no problem.

On the side note, if you are just getting started with your project use **Django 1.5.**

Answer (score 0):

Well you cannot log into the same website with different login ids simultaneously until and unless you dont use some plugins for this feature or you are opening different ids in the incognito window.

Since admin is a superuser(still a user), hence you cannot open a multiple django accounts in the same browser. One account will be logged out in order to open the other one. This is no issue. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

The Django admin site is just another page of your Django main website. Say if you have `foo.com`, then `foo.com/admin/` shows you the admin portal.

And we already know that two users cannot be simultaneously logged in to the same website from the same browser.

So, you can test on your `foo.com` site, being an admin user itself. Experience on the Django website for any user will be same, it doesn't change with user being a staff member or superuser. Only admin site has different permissions based on these factors.
In this case, you'll be able to use both the main site, as well as admin portal.

But if you really want to use different user accounts for admin site and main site, then you should either use different browsers or **Private window** in Firefox.

Comment: You can also access the site with different host names. For example, on a linux system, you can give different names to the same ip by modifying the `/etc/hosts` file.

Comment: Yes, it can be surely done. But if the host name of the 2 sites are different, then this login issue itself wouldn't have occurred as the browser saves the cookies based on domain name.